# Recent detailed documentation for Visual Studio Setup Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-setup-proje

Where is the documentation for the Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 Setup Project extensions? F1 searches inside Visual Studio take me to the docs for VS2010, e.g. [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4awx1f1d(v=vs.100).aspx). The [download page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects) for the VS2015 extension doesn't have a link to any documentation either. I’ve had no luck Googling for it.

Is there updated documentation for 2015 and 2017 or is the 2010 material all there is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2010 documentation is all there is, and that's because there have been no functional updates since then.

Installer projects were taken out of Visual Studio at one time (VS 2012 I believe) and then later made available as a separate add-on. They are in maintenance mode as far as I know, that's the best you can hope for.